# libsqlite3 issue: I am not able to use cl-sql

Tags: sqlite, lisp, common-lisp, clsql

I am trying to use `cl-sql` for database access to `sqlite3`.

But I am getting the error

```
Couldn't load foreign libraries "libsqlite3", "sqlite3". (searched CLSQL-SYS:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-SEARCH-PATHS*: (#P"/usr/lib/clsql/" #P"/usr/lib/"))
```

The same is with `sqlite`.

I have installed `sqlite3` using `apt-get` and there is a file `libsqlite.so.0` in `/usr/lib` directory.

I also tried to build `sqlite3` from source but I couldn't get the `so` file. What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed the development headers? Usually they would be in a package like `libsqlite3-dev`.

Comment: Thanks.  I think it is working now.  However, I cannot find any `libsqlite3.so` in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib/clsql`. Anyway, it is connecting to `sqlite3` database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that cl-sql has a third party dependency. If you inspect the implementation of cl-sql (probably under "~/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/clsql-202011220-git/db-sqlite3/sqlite3-loader.lisp") you will see that the function `database-type-load-foreign` is trying to load a library named either "libsqlite3" or "sqlite3".

Depending on your operating system this is either looking for a .dll or .so with exactly one of those names.

Given that the version of of libsqlite.so has a different name on your particular distribution of linux, you have a number of different options to make this library work.

1. Install a version of sqlite3 with the correct binary
2. Create a soft link to your binary that redirects via `ln -s /usr/lib/libsqlite.so.0 /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so` (assuming libsqlite.so.0 is the file that clsql is looking for)
3. Add new paths to `CLSQL-SYS:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-SEARCH-PATHS*` to point to the correct binary if it is installed elsewhere (via `clsql:push-libary-path`)